# ms access vba code I can disable a field based on content of another field, but my code to re-enable is not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a simple form where I have a field `InstrumentTypes_ID` and a field `DGLenders_ID`.

When `InstrumentTypes_ID` equals `"Mortgage"` or `"Modification"`, I want `DGLenders_ID` to stay enabled, but any other value should make `DGLenders_ID` become disabled.

I have the following code in an AfterUpdate for the `InstrumentTypes_ID` `textBox`, which to me seems would be sufficient to get this effect (However, when testing, I can type in `"Warranty Deed"` (or anything that's not `"Mortgage"` or `"Modification"`), which disables the `DGLenders_ID field`, but if I go back and update it with `"Mortgage"` or `"Modification"`, it won't re-enable that field):

```
Private Sub InstrumentTypes_ID_AfterUpdate()    

    Me.DGLenders_ID.Enabled = True

        If Me.InstrumentTypes_ID = "Mortgage" Then

            Me.DGLenders_ID.Enabled = True

        ElseIf Me.InstrumentTypes_ID = "Modification" Then

            Me.DGLenders_ID.Enabled = True

        Else

            Me.DGLenders_ID.Enabled = False

        End If    

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the value of `Me.InstrumentTypes_ID` what you think it is?  Maybe it's an identifier instead of the expected string?  When you debug this, what is its value?

Comment: you should avoid using same name for controls and data-fields. try renaming your control using prefix like txt_instrument_type_id.
use : me.[data-field] = value or me.controlname.value = value

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put your code in a subroutine and call it on the current event of the form and in the lost focus event of the field.